# md5sum different on linux and windows

Tags: windows, linux, linux-kernel, debian

I am facing a weird problem. md5sum of same text file is different on windows and linux. I expected it to be the same since hash is generated using the content present in the file and does not depend on operating system. is there any specific reason that it is happening like this? Is this same for sha1sum too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the line endings in your text file.  Windows uses CR-LF, Linux uses NL.  The "same text file" has different representations on the two systems, and should have a different md5sum.  You should be able to avoid the difference by opening the file as a binary file in Windows.

Comment: How would you open a file as a binary in Windows and calculate its md5 value using HashTool or other tools?

Answer (score 1):

This is not weird since the content present *is* dependent on the OS.
Windows and Linux use different line feeds Look this  [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1941596)